Inheriting popup multiple composition levels up
Note. In a way, it's a follow-up to this question
Suppose you have a composition of three Swing components. The uppermost component has a popup set. Other components don't. The lowermost component has, say, a MouseWheelListener (a regular MouseListener will do as well). Because of that circumstance, it will take the right click event for processing and ignore it (see the linked question for more details)
There's a property called inheritsPopupMenu. It has a serious limitation: it looks for a popup only one composition level up. That means you have to invoke the property setter N times where N is "tree height - 1". In my example, it's 2, but it could be a lot more in a real production app
That makes that approach somewhat unfeasible in a real-life scenario
My expectations: take the lowermost component and look for a popup; if it's not there, search for a popup all the way up, invoke the first found popup (if it's at all found)
So what is a better way to make Swing popups work according to my expectations?
MRE:
package demos.popup;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

/**
 * The popup is broken. Uncomment the commented out lines to make it work
 */
public class PopupDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup Demo");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JComponent createMainPanel() {
        JComponent mainComp = createPanelWithPopup();
        return mainComp;
    }

    private static JPanel createPanelWithPopup() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Popup Panel";
            }

        };
        panel.setComponentPopupMenu(createPopupMenu());
        panel.add(createChild());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,150));
        return panel;
    }

    private static JComponent createChild() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Child Panel";
            }
        };
        //panel.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
        panel.add(createGrandchild());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JComponent createGrandchild() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Grandchild Panel";
            }
        };
        //panel.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
        panel.addMouseWheelListener(e -> {
        });
        return panel;
    }

    private static JPopupMenu createPopupMenu() {
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.add(createTestMenuItem());
        return popupMenu;
    }

    private static JMenuItem createTestMenuItem() {
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Test menu item");
        menuItem.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Test menu item triggered..."));
        return menuItem;
    }
}


If your window doesn’t change after being built, you can just write a recursive method that calls setInheritsPopupMenu(true) on every component in the tree.  Another possibility is using Toolkit.addAWTEventListener to monitor all mouse and keyboard events.
